# Listeners to dynamically created Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am dynamically creating `jTABLES`. The number of `jTABLES` depends on the database.

```
while(rset.next())
{
        //Create Scroll Pane
        JScrollPane newScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        //Create Table
        JTable newTable = new JTable();
        //Add Table to Scroll Pane
        newScrollPane.setViewportView(newTable);
        //Add Scroll Pane to a Tabbed Pane
        jTabbedPane1.addTab(rset.getString(1),newTable);
}
```

I need to add `MouseListener` to each `jTABLE`, it is basically the same Listener, same actions.

```
while(rset.next())
{
      //Table Created.....
      newTable.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           String data = newTable.getValueAt(0,0).toString();
      }
      //More Abstract Methods...


     });
}
```

Netbeans, forces me to make new Table `final`, and as far as I know, that `final` variables cannot be changed later, is there something wrong here? Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: Any idea why netbeans is making you declare newTable as Final? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @yourdeveloperfriend Netbeans forces me to make it FINAL whenever I try to use it inside the Listener, in the example I provided, its `String data = newTable.getValueAt(0,0).toString();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final variables can't be changed later but do you need to change the final local variables out of the `while` loop?

If yes carete an array or list and store the references there.

final is required to use the reference in anonimous inner class (your listener).

Comment: Creating tables and adding Mouse Listeners to them are inside a private method, that method is placed in the constructors where it will be executed at start up, is this the right way?

Comment: So should I leave it as it be? make it Final? Even if there will be many tables?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a variable(outside variable) inside annonymous inner classes, it is necessary that it is declared final. That's why netbeans is forcing you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to avoid the final problem:

Create another class that implements MouseListener.

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseListener {
    JTable table;
    public MyMouseListener(JTable table) {
      this.table = table;
    }
```

Then use that table in any of the methods.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   String data = table.getValueAt(0,0).toString();
}
```

then add that mouse listener to the table.

```
myTable.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(myTable));
```